# bash: vue: command not found - when making vite app

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vuejs3, vite

I've started new vue3 project, using vite, and want to add vuetify (even though it's alpha) to it. The tutorials says use "vue add vuetify", but all I get is "command not found error". What am I missing? This is what I've ran:

```
yarn create vite hof --template vue
cd hof
yarn
vue add vuetify
bash: vue: command not found
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to install `@vue/cli` first:

```sh
$ yarn global add @vue/cli
```

And then try the command:

```sh
$ vue add vuetify
```